# Chartjs - custom y axis range

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I wanted to add custom y axis range to chartjs. Currently its picking automatically.My data range is too large so *min and max* doesn't work properly,most of the items are invisible in that case.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gCAL.png)

I wanted to add some custom y axis range some thing like this

[Range Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YnYd.png)

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Please check this:
https://therichpost.com/question/how-to-change-the-labels-of-chart-js-graph-yaxes

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome..hope your problem has been solved

Answer (score 4):

I am able to fix this issue by following configurations.

```
yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'LABEL',
        },
        type: 'logarithmic',
        position: 'left',
        ticks: {
             min: 0, //minimum tick
             max: 10000000, //maximum tick
             callback: function (value, index, values) {
                 return Number(value.toString());//pass tick values as a string into Number function
             }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function (chartObj) { //Build ticks labelling as per your need
            chartObj.ticks = [0,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000];
        }
    }]
```

Comment: could you add a fiddle